# Can not get passed the login screen

Tags: unity, 12.04, login

I have the same issue as others (see Login returns to login screen [closed]).

When I arrived at the login screen, I enter my password, the screen goes black for one second, displaying some text, and then it returns me to a fresh login screen.

I can go to a console alt+f1 and login into my account on the command line.

It is a fairly fresh install of ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, plenty of room left on the home dir. Permissions on the home directory are okay 755. Only one user.

Any hint because I cannot fix this apparently... Thanks!

Oh yes: the xsession-errors log says: "mkdtemp: private socket dir: Permission denied".
Reinstalled unity, to no avail.

Comment: what does `ls -ld /tmp` say? It should start with `drwxrwxrwt .. root root`. Notice the `w`'s and the `t` in `rwt`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed /tmp permissions: sudo chmod a+wt /tmp

Comment: I'll add it as an answer so it can easily be found by others.

Answer (score 4):

Check the permission bits on `/tmp`:

```
ls -ld /tmp
```

```
drwxrwxrwt 6 root root 296 May 12 10:57 /tmp
  ^  ^  ^^
```

Escpecially notice the `w`'s and the `t` at the start of the line. If you have different permission bits, change it using:

```
sudo chmod a+wt /tmp
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped! Any ideas how could this happen, if I did not `sudo chmod a-w /tmp` ?