# Can't Log in to Lubuntu 12.04 X Server

Tags: xorg, 64-bit, login, lubuntu

As of rebooting yesterday I can't login as myself to the `X` server part of `64-bit Lubuntu 12.04`. Same problem as [Can not get passed the login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135666/can-not-get-passed-the-login-screen) but that solution didn't work for me.

*Troubleshooting steps I already took:* I can

1. log in as guest (with whatever window manager) to the graphic (`X`) view of `Lubuntu`.
2. log in as myself into a virtual terminal. (In fact I'm writing this from `w3m` for that reason.)

So I know my password is correct and that most aspects of the system are working. One of the top google results for "can't log into lubuntu" mentioned a disk-full problem on netbooks; I don't have that problem.

**Let me know if I need to paste any messages or config files to make this question clearer and I'll do so.**

`$ ls -l /home`

```
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 99 me me 12288 May 26 14:16 me
```

`$ ls -ld /tmp`

```
drwxrwxrwt  16 root root 4096 May 26 15:46 /tmp
```

Comment: Check the [Can not get passed the login screen][1] thread. Some directory permissions are probably wrong.


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/135666/can-not-get-passed-the-login-screen/135890#135890

Comment: If the first comment doesn't help, check the output to `ls -l /home` and add it to your question.

Comment: @jippie Thank you! Unfortunately that did not help.

Answer (score 2):

I had that exact same problem.

Turns out I had just messed up my .profile script.

I logged in using Alt + Ctl + F1 at the login screen and fixed the error.

Comment: What was wrong with your `.profile` script?

Comment: I introduced a typo while editing it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem too.

As panos2point0 mention something messed up in my *.profile* script.
The easiest way to know what's the problem is login with tty and do **`cat ~/.xsession-errors`** it will show your what's the problem and which line the problem occur.

Comment: Thanks. That is a huge log file. What am I looking for in it?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that there is more than one way to mess this up.

I've just had the same problem, was about to give up and install debian but my lost pendrive made me figure this out.

It turned out that i had changed my login password, but since my home folder was encrypted it couldn't decrypt it with my new password.

My temporary solution was to go back to the old password. I will figure out how to change the encryption password later.

Comment: I've had problems with `ecryptfs` before (I should have never done it, it was just a button I could hit "yes" to and decided "Hey why not, Ubuntu is stable, I can push all the buttons here"). But that's not the issue this time. (I don't think.)