# Kubuntu 12.04 fails to login

Tags: kubuntu, boot-failure

I've just installed kubuntu 12.04 but I've got a problem here. When I login it shows the starting splash screen of KDE but when it gets to the fourth icon it stops and the screen goes black, only showing the mouse pointer.
I'd really like to test this distro, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Strike <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> to logon to the text console.

Check this thread: [Can not get passed the login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135666/can-not-get-passed-the-login-screen/135890).

Strike <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> to logon to return to your graphics console.

Comment: Additionally while in the text console, you can check `less ~/.xsession-errors` for interesting looking messages.

Comment: ok so I've got to text console and then do the permission thingy and return to graphical interface, I'll give it a shot

Comment: well, that didn't work... Te permissions are exactly what they should be. One ore thing that could be interesting: during the booting before the login screen my screen turns off for a couple of seconds and then turns on again. I'm not sure if it is relevant but I'm trying to give all the information needed.

Comment: My monitors go to sleep for a few seconds during boot. I think it is normal behaviour.